# Problem with X DISPLAY when open3d draw geometry used

Tags: python, glfw, open3d

When using open3d and trying to get a 3d mesh, I get the following error:

```
[1;33m[Open3D WARNING] GLFW Error: X11: Failed to open display :0.0[0;m
[1;33m[Open3D WARNING] Failed to initialize GLFW[0;m
[1;33m[Open3D WARNING] [DrawGeometries] Failed creating OpenGL window.[0;m
```

I tried using Xming with X11 enabled and giving the IP address of the Linux environment in cluster where the code is written, and using putty I tried to export `display=(Linux IP address):(port number)` in the terminal after connecting to SSH through putty. It didn't work.

How can I resolve this error to get the display active ?

Comment: `display` is distinct from `DISPLAY`. This does not seem like a programming question.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? To render headlessly there is this in Open3D http://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/tutorial/visualization/headless_rendering.html but I assume you do want to visualize the objects.

Answer (score 3):

Change `o3d.visualization.draw_geometries` to `o3d.visualization.draw_plotly`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As [Mansi said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75652646/2745495), replace it with `draw_plotly()`.

For example:

```py
o3d.visualization.draw_plotly([to_o3d_pcd(horse_xyz, horse_normal), to_o3d_mesh(v, f)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `draw_plotly()` function of open3d.

Comment: If you are unsure please delete this and wait for your commenting privilege. Otherwise please try for [answer].